# How to change the text of selected text in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, selected

I want to change the text of selected text in JTextArea.

For example when i press button i want the selected text to be change (Original Text Selected - I want to replace like this when i press the button : Replace:Original Text Selected) this is what i am trying to do in my code,

```
String replacement = "Replace:" + messageBodyText.getSelectedText() ";
```

but i have no idea how to change only selected text i am trying to do something but i am changing entire text of JTextArea Hope you understood my question ?

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels he solved my problem this is my code for other people who are facing the same problem :

```
int start = messageBodyText.getSelectionStart();
            int end = messageBodyText.getSelectionEnd();

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(messageBodyText.getText());
            strBuilder.replace(start, end, "Replace:" + messageBodyText.getSelectedText() + ".");
            messageBodyText.setText(strBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
textComponent.replaceSelection(newText);
```

Answer (score 6):

JTextComponent (and thus JTextArea) has `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` methods that will help you. Get your text from the JTextArea or its Document, and using these int values you can change your text and replace it into the text component.

For example,

```
int start = myTextField.getSelectionStart();
int end = myTextField.getSelectionEnd();
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(myTextField.getText());
strBuilder.replace(start, end, newText);
myTextField.setText(strBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Hey dude thank you 

You are my hero i was close but without you i am sure i would waste another 240 minutes

Comment: @user112862: glad it could help. One secret though: I did not know these methods 15 minutes ago, but I figured that they or something like them must exist, and a quick peak at the JTextComponent API revealed them to me. This is a useful heuristic for me and can work well for you too.

Comment: Thank you again i learn another thing from you but sometime brain doesn't work when you work hard and when you are novice next time i am going to rest and then come back and try to  fix it . Thank you again

Comment: for future reference there is a method that does this for you :) Check out my answer below.

Comment: @user112862: please "un-accept" my answer and instead "accept" camickr's. It is clearly the better of the two.